# How to derive the transfer function of the Inverting Summing Amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, inverting-amplifier, summing

I know that the transfer function of an inverting summing amplifier gives this, by using the Superposition principle: *(for example with 2 input voltages)*

\$U_{ out }=-(\frac { R_{ 1 } }{ R_{ f } } U_{ in1 }+\frac { R_{ 2 } }{ R_{ f } } U_{ in2 })\$

However, I don't exactly know how to derive this from the transfer function definition:

\$H = U_{out}/U_{in} = G(U_{+}-U_{-})/U_{in}\$

[image: Inverting Summing Op-Amp]

This is not explained in any book or on the Web. Can anyone explain this?

*Thanks a lot!*

Comment: U+ is zero and U- can be found using again superposition. That`s all. But you have to realize that there are TWO transfer functions because you have two input voltages, unless you define Uin as the sum of both input signals.

Comment: I know that U+ is 0.

Comment: So, I need to transfer functions and then sum them? Like:
H1 = Uout/Uin1 and 
H2 = Uout/Uin2
?

Comment: Ok! I got it! I did it by having 2 transfer functions! Would you like to post it as an answer so that I accept it?

Comment: I think it is OK so. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested how I derived the transfer function, here is the solution:

*(This is the derivation for the schematic as shown in the question. If you have more inputs, just do the same procedure for each one.)*

[image: Transfer function derivation]

So, **the solution was to have as many transfer functions as your inputs**, and then the derivation is the same as an Inverting Amplifier.